# Linux (suse) is routing without permission

Tags: iptables

my configuration is simple:

```
client <172.168.178.111><------><172.168.178.1:eth1>-- linuxbox --<br0:131.100.100.1>----> global net
```

i am trying to install a NAT net. As mentioned, the local net is 172.168.178.0 (Windows) which i want to nat to the outside world.

There are NO rules for mangle, FORWARD, POSTROUTING, PREROUTING.

The problems are
1) I installing a NAT oder MASQUERADE does nothing:

```
a) iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.178.0/24 -o br0 -j SNAT --to-source 131.100.100.1
b) iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o br0 -j MASQUERADE
```

when i do a "ping" from client to an address in the global world, the interface on the br0 is always showing the origin address of 192.168.178.111 (with wireshark logged): no MASQUERADE or Natting where done

2) i can prevent the communication when i drop the packages on the FORWARD Queue:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
```

But that is not very clever because then the whole communication is blocked.
I could block the forwarding ("0" to /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward) on the Linux box but that has the same effect: no packet is routed.

I thought that iptables is intervened by "route":

```
Ziel            Router          Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         131.100.100.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
131.100.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br0
192.168.178.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

But that are the necessary rules for routing.

Are there some ideas?

regards

Comment: I had a type fpr the NAT command, it should be:  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -d 192.168.178.0/24 -o br0 -j SNAT --to-source 131.100.100.1

Comment: Note: i noticed that the client had the wrong default gateway which is the gateway of the linuxbox: 172.168.178.1. After changing that, it seems that NAT is working (no client address shows up on br0). But something seems to still  block the answers from outside to the client.